# Sync AD user properties to Sharepoint Online List

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to create an employee directory on a SharePoint online list from our local AD users properties. I have created the list on SharePoint with the properties(Full Name, Email, Mobile Phone, and Work Phone). I have also installed the Microsoft on-premise gateway on a local server and verified it on powerapps.

What could I use to get the data from the local AD users to the SharePoint online list?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the users in your Active Directory you need to use the Microsoft Graph.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0

[image: Example code]

Comment: It seems the microsoft graph would need to be implemented at the O365 Admin level, but i do not have that level of admin access. I do not have the access level on our O365 items but i do have all the access rights to our local AD.

Comment: It doesn't need to be implemented at the admin level but an administrator would have to grant the permissions necessary to access the user profiles